# PHP get value of row field from inside of while loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Suppose I have a table like this:

Table `swipes`

```
swp_id    swp_by    swp_to    swp_type    swp_date
1           8          1       top        2020-03-24 02:39:12
2           11         1       right      2020-03-18 02:37:58
3           1          8       right      2020-03-31 04:04:40
4           1         11       top        2020-03-31 04:04:40
```

Based on which I have my setup like this:

```
<?php
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM swipes WHERE swp_by = :mem AND swp_type != 'left' ORDER BY swp_id DESC");
  $stmt-> bindValue(':mem', $sessionUser);
  $stmt-> execute();

  while($swp = $stmt->fetch()){
      $match = $pdo->prepare("SELECT swp_id, swp_date FROM swipes WHERE swp_by = :by AND swp_to = :to AND swp_type != 'left'");
      $match-> bindValue(':by', $swp['swp_by']);
      $match-> bindValue(':to', $sessionUser);
      $match-> execute();

      while($mat = $match->fetch()){
?>
  <!-- Some HTML Part here to display fetched data as per second while loop -->
<?php } } ?>
```

As you can see right now I have `ORDER BY swp_id DESC` in first query which works fine. But when I try removing from 1st query and adding it in second query it doesn't work. What I actually want to do is to get the time from the latest swipe.

As you can see in table given above for the 1st two rows with `swp_id` 1 & 2, Users 8 and 11 swiped user 1 first. Later, user 1 swiped users 8 & 11 as you can see in records with `swp_id` 3 & 4. Now, record 3 & 4 are the latest records. Hence, I want to fetch the `swp_date` from these records and not from 1 & 2. Right now, it's returning date from records 1 and 2.

Comment: Maybe if you showed us data from both the relevant tables it would help us to understand your situation

Comment: @RiggsFolly rest of the tables here are not mandatory. I will update the question.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have updated the question. Only 1 table is concerned. I didn't bother to clean that up earlier. But those tables didn't matter to this problem however.

Comment: I think you're mixing up your `swipe_by` and `swipe_to` values. `ORDER` only sorts the data you're retrieving, it has nothing to do with WHAT you select.

Comment: @Michel no those values are okay. If I say in short, what I actually want here is to get the `swp_date` value from records 3 & 4 instead of 1 & 2 as records 3 & 4 the matching records for 1 & 2 and appeared second.

Comment: 1st query: `WHERE swp_by = :mem`, 2nd query: `swp_by = :by`. If :mem=1 in first, then :by in second also is 1 (`:by=$swp['swp_by']`)

Comment: Apart from that, you could retrieve the data with one query using a simple JOIN

Comment: @Michel you mean to say its possible joining a table with self? Can you please post an answer as per my code so that I get a full sense of what you are trying to say?

Comment: Yes you can, `SELECT FROM swipes T1 LEFT JOIN swipes T2 ON ...` But I still don't exactly know what data you want to retrieve. Is it all swipedates from user 1 where there is also a "swipe back" (so they both swiped each other)

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want all the user_id's and dates from users that swiped to **user_id 1**, but only if he(she) swiped that user too, and not to the left.

So extending your table a bit:

```
swp_by  swp_to  swp_type    swp_date
   8      1       top         ...
   8      4       top         ... <not
   11     1       top         ...
   1      8       top         ...
   1      11      top         ...
   20     1       top         ... < not
   1      40      top         ... < not
   1      41      left        ... < not
```

First part: select all the swipes from **user 1** `swp_by = 1` that are not left (the same as your first query):

```
// :mem = 1
SELECT swp_id, swp_by, swp_to, swp_date 
    FROM swipes
    WHERE swp_by = :mem AND swp_type <> "left"
```

**Result 1:**

```
swp_by  swp_to  swp_type    swp_date
   1      8        top         ...
   1     11        top         ...
   1     40        top         ... <not
```

Second part: find all the swipes "back" to **user 1**, so where `swp_to = 1`

```
// :mem = 1
SELECT swp_id, swp_by, swp_to, swp_date 
    FROM swipes
    WHERE swp_to = :mem AND swp_type <> "left"
```

**Result 2:**

```
swp_by  swp_to  swp_type    swp_date
   8      1       top         ...
   11     1       top         ...
   20     1       top         ... < not
```

Now you can cross reference the results finding the `swp_to` numbers from **Result 1** (8, 11, 40) that have a `swp_by` in **Result 2** (8, 11, 20). This can be done using a `LEFT JOIN` from the same table

```
//this, in combination with WHERE, gives Result 1
SELECT R1.swp_id, R1.swp_to, R1.swp_type , GREATEST(R1.swp_date,R2.swp_date)

    FROM swipes AS R1

//cross reference with Result 2
LEFT JOIN swipes AS R2
    ON ( 
    //look for those records where R1.swipe_to = R2.swipe_by
    R1.swp_to = R2.swp_by 
        AND
    //swipe_to from Result 2 has to be user 1
    R2.swp_to = R1.swp_by
        AND 
    //no left swipes in Result 2
    R2.swp_type <> "left" 
    )

WHERE 
    //look only at the records from user 1...
    R1.swp_by = :mem 
        AND
    //...that are not empty
    R2.swp_by IS NOT NULL
            AND
    //... that not are left
    R1.swp_type <> 'left' 
ORDER BY R1.swp_id DESC
```

Here's a [new fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae06342/10)
***EDIT** OP wanted latest date, adjusted with `GREATEST` for date

Comment: I saw your fiddle. You nearly got everything right. The only thing missing is that it's still not giving result according to the latest record. In your fiddle if we take record 11 & 12, we can see that 1 swiped 10 first at record 11 and therefore, it was not the latest record. The date should have been shown for record 12 where user 10 swiped 1 later making it the latest record. The date shown should have been 12th Jan and not 11th Jan. The date there means the date when user 1 & 10 actually got matched. When user 1 swiped 10 on 11th Jan, they were not a match.... (next comment)

Comment: They became a match on 12th Jan when 10 swiped user 1 back. Please see, you are nearly there and that's the actual problem I am stuck upon.

Comment: Adjusted the query and the fiddle, they now give what you want. But in future cases, explain better what it is you want.

Comment: fixed the fiddle

Comment: Thank you.. Now I have what I wanted to have. Thanks for so much efforts. I will be thankful forever :)

Answer (score 0):

if you start from SessionUser=8, the first loop recover swp_by=8, the swp_id=1. Then the inner loop ask for swp_by=8 and swp_to=8, that is no results. You only see the results of first loop. I suppose that you have to review your second query. Maybe:

```
$match-> bindValue(':by', $swp['swp_to']);
$match-> bindValue(':to', $swp['swp_by']);
```

Comment: in the second loop the select could be modifyed : 
  while($swp = $stmt->fetch()){
      $match = $pdo->prepare("SELECT swp_id, swp_date FROM swipes WHERE swp_to = :to AND swp_type != 'left'");
      $match-> bindValue(':to', $sessionUser);
      $match-> execute();